# How to test(Integration tests) springboot-kafka microservices

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have Spring-boot Kafka pub sub microserivces as shows in the figure. I want to do Integration tests for each of my apps.

[image]

**UseCase1:** **SpringBoot-App-c**  which `consumes` from `Topic X` and process it and `produces` to `Topic Y`.

**UseCase2:** **SpringBoot-App-b** just consumes from `Topic X` and process it

**Expected:**
 In my test I want to publish a message to `Topic X`(intended for Springboot-app-c) which should be processed by **Spring-Boot-App-C** and produces to `Topic Y` and I want to confirm whether that particular message is produced to topic Y or not .

**Drawbacks:**  when I produce a message to Topic X which is intended for `Springboot-app-c` along with `Springboot-app-c, springboot-app-b and spring-boot-app-d` are picking it. When i tried to test one app- it is testing three apps unknowingly and i want more control on it.  I want the test message to be picked up by `spring-boot-app-c` only. How do I make it app specific and test each app separately

- How to know something was published to topic Y
- How to have only one and right consumer from  topic X for a test message for that particular app

Answer (score 2):

> How to know something was published to topic Y

Add a consumer to the test for topic Y to verify you received the expected data.

> How to have only one and right consumer from topic X for a test message for that particular app

You can't; there is no mechanism in Kafka for conditional routing or message selection. All consumer groups get a copy of the message.

You would have to use separate topics.